# How recognized its Custom exception or Predefined Exception? In Java

Tags: java

I have tried to find blog for this anwser but i dont get anything on Google. so anybody can please give some clarification on this question?.

I am actually confused with that. If custom exception is checked exception then how compiler or jvm  recognized. its custom/predefined exception.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: who says it does?

Comment: sorry stultuske. I actually dont know who does this task meas how its recognized and throw custom exception. please give me some clarification if possible

Comment: it throws a specific exception, because the code is written to do so.